Calculate intraday filled orders in pine script
I am trying to figure out how I can keep track and calculate the number of orders that are filled intraday in pine script.
I am using the max.intraday.orders function to limit the strategy per day, but this results in that the position that exceeds the max orders per day just opens and closes straight away.
I need a function to calculate how many orders are filled intraday, so that I can stop the strategy from entering the trade that will push max orders over the limit.

you can calculate number of trades from the beginning of the session by using session.isfirstbar for detection and strategy.closedtrades
